# Real-Time update of markers without loading the page Google Maps API V3

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Im using Google Maps API V3 markers php/sql.
my problem is i want a real time update of markers depending on data stored in my sql db because i need it for my emergency response system for my capstone project. but i see 2 or 3 threads with this same issue but nothing happens when i try to use there codes. please somebody tell me what to do. i'm doing this almost 1 day straight but nothing happens.

What I want to achieve is [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fwaIoGAnWCA).

this is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>PHP/MySQL & Google Maps Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[

    var customIcons = {
      restaurant: {
        icon: 'http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ridefinder-images/mm_20_blue.png'
      },
      bar: {
        icon: 'http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ridefinder-images/mm_20_red.png'
      }
    };

    function load() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.6145, -122.3418),
        zoom: 13,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
      });
      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
      // Change this depending on the name of your PHP fil
     downloadUrl("poy.php", function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
          var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
          var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
          var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address + "<br/>" + point;
          var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            icon: icon.icon
          });
          bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
        }
      });
    }   

    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    }

    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;

      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
          callback(request, request.status);
        }
      };

      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.send(null);
    }

    function doNothing() {}


    //]]>

  </script>

  </head>

  <body onload="load()">
  <div id="map" style="width: 700px; height: 500px"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do you see your markers on first load? You are calling `downloadUrl` only once so it won't refresh. See [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) if you want to call the function repeatedly.

Comment: yes i saw it. but where should i put the code setInterval?. on the function downloadUrl or inside the function load?. please help me sir.

Comment: sir kindly edit my code above and post here the right code for setInterval. Thank You sir.

Answer (score 0):

This is untested but you should get the idea. In your `load()` function, set the interval to trigger a download.

```
var map, infoWindow, intervalId;

var customIcons = {
    restaurant: {
        icon: 'http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ridefinder-images/mm_20_blue.png'
    },
    bar: {
        icon: 'http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ridefinder-images/mm_20_red.png'
    }
};

function load() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.6145, -122.3418),
        zoom: 13,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
    });

    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

    // Trigger downloadUrl at an interval
    intervalId = setInterval(triggerDownload, 5000);
}

function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    });
}

function triggerDownload() {
    // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
    downloadUrl("poy.php", function (data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
            var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
            var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
            var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
            parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
            parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
            var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address + "<br/>" + point;
            var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: point,
                icon: icon.icon
            });
            bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
        }
    });
}

function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
    var request = window.ActiveXObject ? new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') : new XMLHttpRequest;

    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
            request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
            callback(request, request.status);
        }
    };

    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.send(null);
}

function doNothing() {}
```

This will download your XML every 5 seconds (5000 ms).

If you wish to stop the process, you can call

```
clearInterval(intervalId);
```

A word of warning: you are using `XMLHttpRequest` which is asynchronous. This means you could call `downloadUrl` before it finished with the previous request, which could result in unwanted behavior.

Comment: Thank You So Much. i appreciate this answer but im sorry for not saying this i already did this kind of code. the problem of this code is. if i refresh my page, i will wait for 5 seconds to load the markers and then if the markers is loaded the setinterval stops and never loop again.

this is my full files and kindly try it. and see the problem.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/p20vvrxo2uncxx5/poy.rar?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

This code work perfectly for me:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[

   var map, infoWindow, intervalId;

var customIcons = {
    restaurant: {
        icon: 'http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ridefinder-images/mm_20_blue.png'
    },
    bar: {
        icon: 'http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ridefinder-images/mm_20_red.png'
    }
};

function load() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.6145, -122.3418),
        zoom: 13,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
    });

    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

    // Trigger downloadUrl at an interval
    intervalId = setInterval(triggerDownload, 1000);
}

function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    });
}

function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    });
}

var markersArray = [];

function clearOverlays() {
  for (var i = 0; i < markersArray.length; i++ ) {
   markersArray[i].setMap(null);
  }
}

function triggerDownload() {
    clearOverlays();
    // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
    downloadUrl("poy.php", function (data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
            var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
            var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
            var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
            parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
            parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
            var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address + "<br/>" + point;
            var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: point,
                icon: icon.icon
            });
            markersArray.push(marker);
            bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
        }
    });
}

function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
    var request = window.ActiveXObject ? new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') : new XMLHttpRequest;

    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
            request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
            callback(request, request.status);
        }
    };

    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.send(null);
}

function doNothing() {}

    //]]>

  </script>
```